# Assign output of a function to a dataframe column for rows which match a criteria in some other column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe **'df'** with columns **'A'**, **'B'** as shown. I want to create a new column **'C'** and assign it the output of the function **func()**. However, the constraint is that only those rows (in **"C"**) be assigned such values for which the column **"A"** entries match **"abc"**. For such rows, the input variable for the **func()** will be the corresponding entry of **'B'** column.

For example, in attached photo, row 0 and row 2 have column **'A'** values as **'abc'**. For such rows, the value in **'C'** should be calculated by **func()** by using the value in column **'B'** (in this case, either **"2222"** or **"4444"**).

Note: Variables **'var2'**, **'var3'** are some values derived elsewhere in my program. We can treat them as constants for our discussion here.

[image]

I can of course use a 'for loop' and get this accomplished, however, I was wondering if there is any efficient way to do this using pandas or numpy. I tried using the '.where' method but it seems that the func() interprets entire column 'B' as its input rather than taking each element  of the column 'B' (ie... "2222" or "4444").

```
def func(var1, var2, var3):
    <something>
    return(output)

import numpy as np
df['C'] = np.where(data['A'] == 'abc', func(data['B'], var2, var3), " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you could access each item in your dataframe using the `.loc` method and apply your assignment there using `.apply()` :

not sure how many conditions you have but mimicking your code above  :

```
df.loc[df['A'] == 'abc', 'C'] = df['B'].apply(func)
```

for example,

```
import pandas as pd
a = ['abc','b','abc']
b = [1,2,3]
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : a,
              'B' : b})
print(df)
   A  B
0  abc  1
1    b  2
2  abc  3
df.loc[df['A'] == 'abc','C'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x : x ** 2)
   A    B    C
0  abc  1  1.0
1    b  2  NaN
2  abc  3  9.0
```

if your logic is more complex you can use `np.select` as follows:

```
conditions  = [ df['B'] >= 3, (df['B'] < 3) & (df['B']> 1), df['B'] <= 1]
choices     = [ "high", 'medium', 'low' ]

df["C"] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=np.nan)

print(df)
     A  B       C
0  abc  1     low
1    b  2  medium
2  abc  3    high
```

Comment: Hi @Datanovice, thanks for the response.
In my case the func() takes multiple inputs and is like func(var1, var2) where var1 is the value of 'B' column while var2 is a constant. I am wondering how wud your code needs to be modified for '.apply(func)' so as to reflect var1 and var2 as inputs to func(). Can you please advise how your code modifes in such case?

Comment: I am amazed by so many tricks to accomplish this, thank you for your edit! Your suggestion would have normally worked, however, in my case the function 'func(var1, var2)' queries the database elsewhere to derive upon its output (which it returns). This returned value should then be placed in column 'C'. I am wondering if you have any suggestion to accomplish this?    Btw, I editted my original problem description too to make it clearer.

Comment: @Sinha are you able to show a sample of your data and expected output?